# New PHP Versions Rendered My PHP Application Useless. Register_Globals option removed

Tags: php

I wrote a very nice PHP application over 2 years off and on. I made extensive use of the whole

```
if($page == "users") {

//show user page

} else {

// do nothing

}
```

so everything would be clean and organized and included in just a few files. Things like `index.php?page=users` -- I have just started back on this project and I noticed the recent versions of PHP have removed the `register_globals` option which have removed my ability to misuse that "function". `register_globals` by itself isn't insecure, but if the programmer doesn't take into account all of the things that should be secured if that option is on then it could be exploited.

I'm not sure what to do now. I have been reading the new PHP manuals and I looked at a few tutorials but it doesn't make sense to me yet. I had a head injury and I got some brain damage from it so I did lose some of my ability to figure things out fast like I use to be able to.

I tried setting things like `if($page = true) { do_something }` but that didn't work either.

Comment: `if($page = true)` is assignment that sets `$page` to `true`.  You may see where the constant values (`true` in this case) are put on the left `if(true = $page)` that is done because you cant set `true` to something so PHP will issue an error, unlike the other way around.

Comment: Also there are other things that do 'like' register_globals, for example `extract($_GET)` in your case.  Which will create a variable named `$page = 'users'`, another one is `list()`  etc..

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit behind the times. `register_globals` was deprecated in PHP 5.3 (which was released in 2014) and removed entirely in PHP 5.4 (which was released in 2015).

Variables set in query parameters are present in the `$_GET` superglobal array. For instance, if you needed to test the value of a `page` query parameter (like `index.php?page=example`), you could do so using:

```
if ($_GET["page"] == "users") {
    …
```

If you need to use the value of a single query parameter in multiple places, you could instead assign it to a variable:

```
$page = $_GET["page"];
```

Comment: I just read your comment after I had already figured it out! I read the $_GET information page on PHP and I understood it. I wrote it like this intead: if ($_GET["page"] == "1") { show_something } else { nothing }} and it seems to work. Now I'm left wondering if this is secure or not. Is this vulnerable to any kind of attacks or injections or maybe URL injections?

Answer (score 0):

Your first if statement is set up correctly, so I can only assume that $page isn't getting set properly. You might want to consult a quick tutorial on how to use GET variables, since you want the value to be in the URL itself. I recommend something like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm), but since this is pretty basic, any GET tutorial should work.

Answer (score -1):

Instead, what you should be doing is something like this:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;
```

Or in PHP7+ you can use the new null coalescing operator `??`:

```
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? false;
```

Both of these check if page was set as part of the query string if not then it sets `$page` to boolean false.  If so, then it's the value that was passed though the query string.

Comment: I want to be sure an attacker can't manipulate the URL to do anything malicious. This is for a Content Management System I haven't updated in several years. I am going back through and upgrading all of the security features and making it compatible with the most recent PHP versions. I read they are dropping security support for PHP versions before 7. All of my code needs to be updated. I changed things like if ($Page == "News") { show_news } to instead if ($_GET["Page"] == "News") { show_news } and that seemed to fix that problem. but is it secure?